# json parsing: GET elements if their exist in each in insertion

Tags: json, parsing, multidimensional-array

I need to get all the data from my json FB file.
Some insertion for example, few fields have "likes" but others dont.
I need to check if the field "like" exists

An example of my data is this:

```
{
"userdata": 
[
{
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "from": {
      "name": "my name",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "message": "Hello",
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Comment",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/"
      },
      {
        "name": "Like",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/"
      }
    ],
    "privacy": {
      "description": "Friends",
      "value": "ALL_FRIENDS",
      "friends": "",
      "networks": "",
      "allow": "",
      "deny": ""
    },
    "type": "status",
    "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
    "application": {
      "name": "Graph API Explorer",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "created_time": "2013-12-25T15:22:43+0000",
    "updated_time": "2013-12-25T15:22:43+0000",
    **"likes"**: {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "name": "friend1"
        },
        {
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "name": "friend2"
        }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "after": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
          "before": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "from": {
      "name": "name3",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "to": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "my name",
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      ]
    },
    "message": "hello again! ",
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Comment",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
        "name": "Like",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "privacy": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "type": "status",
    "application": {
      "name": "Facebook for iPad",
      "namespace": "fbipad_",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "created_time": "2013-12-17T20:34:04+0000",
    "updated_time": "2013-12-17T20:34:04+0000"
  }
]
}
```

I use the following code but I get only the first insertion and not both because the second does not have the field "likes".

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
});
$("#loaduserdata").click(function(){
$("#userdata tbody").html("");
$.getJSON("js.json", function(data){
        $.each(data.userdata, function(i,user){
            var tblRow =
                "<tr>"
                +"<td>FEED FROM: "+user.from.name+"</td>"
                +"<td>MESSAGE: "+user.message+"</td>"
                +"<td>created_time: "+user.created_time+"</td>"
                +"<td>updated_time: "+user.updated_time+"</td>"
                + "<td>LIKES TO" + (typeof user.likes.data == "undefined" ? "" :     user.likes.data.map(function(item) { return "  "+item.name; }).join(", "))     + "</td>"
                +"</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
    }
);
});
</script>
```

HELP please.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check if user.likes exists and only check for user.likes.data, but that check already throws an error because you try to access the property data on an undefined object.

```
function getLikesFromUser(user) {
    if (user.likes && user.likes.data) {
        return user.likes.data.map(function(item) {
            return item.name;
        }).join(", ");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

[Fixed Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2sOtH54KbrNxNV0B8Yme?p=preview)

Comment: the example on Plunker does not open. Where should i use this functions? In the place of what?

Comment: I can not find I reason why I should not work. You can define that function somewhere and use it within you each function. The user object is the same as in your each. So you can call `var likes = getLikesFromUser(user);` and put the likes string in your table `"<td>LIKES TO" + likes  + "</td>"`

Comment: OK, sorry, my mistake... Thank you!